# setting hypothesis based on 2 independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, predictor, dependent-variable, research-design

Normally, we have one main IV and other covariates and show relationship with DV. Based on the main IV we conceptualize the research question and hypothesise. Say, Income (IV), Mental Health (DV) plus other variables as Education, Race, Sex. My question is I can have my Hypo I as: higher income is associated with better mental health. But can I make Hypo II as: Higher Education (another IV) is associated with better mental health, and so on Hypo III: Males are more likely than females to have mental health. Is it possible to have all these in the same construct?

Like the equation is: DV~X1+X2+X3...Xk
hypo1: association between X1 and DV
hypo2: association between X2 and DV
hypo3: association between X3 and DV
If this makes any sense.

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: Normally, we have one main IV and other covariates and show relationship with DV. Based on the main IV we conceptualize the research question and hypothesise. Say, Income (IV), Mental Health (DV) plus other variables as Education, Race, Sex. My question is I can have my Hypo I as: higher income is associated with better mental health. But can I make Hypo II as: Higher Education (another IV) is associated with better mental health, and do on...Hypo III: Males are more likely than females to have mental health. Is it possible to have all these in the same construct?

Comment: @utobi I phrased a little bit above. Basically, can we propose hypotheses from all or more than one of the independent variables? I'm under the impression that one main I.V. is used to propose hypotheses.

Comment: Please, consider updating the post accordingly.

Comment: @utobi I did post the updated question.